# Spring Batch application fails without any ERROR message

Tags: java, spring-batch

Requirement:

Read from the file containing 100K records.

For each records, retrieve data from IBM DB2 database table and then retrieve data from NuoDB database table.

At last, insert the updated records in the NuoDB database table.

Design approached: Chunk-oriented processing where 1000 records will be read from the file and processed and written into the database.

Issue: After approx 14K records and running for almost 1 hour, the batch application failed with the below error:

```
2020-06-12 22:00:00.084 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'repository1'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.084 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select DB2_TABLE.* from TABLE1 DB2_TABLE where DB2_TABLE.COLUMN1=?
Hibernate: select DB2_TABLE.* from TABLE1 DB2_TABLE where DB2_TABLE.COLUMN1=?
2020-06-12 22:00:00.086 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [           main] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2020-06-12 22:00:00.086 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fInputRepository'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.086 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select NuoDB_TABLE.* from TABLE2 NuoDB_TABLE where NuoDB_TABLE.COLUMN1=?
Hibernate: select NuoDB_TABLE.* from TABLE2 NuoDB_TABLE where NuoDB_TABLE.COLUMN1=?
2020-06-12 22:00:00.180  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2a7f1f10: startup date [Fri Jun 12 21:00:11 BST 2020]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3972a855
2020-06-12 22:00:00.182 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.185 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.185 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.185 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.185  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2020-06-12 22:00:00.186 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Asking bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean] to stop
2020-06-12 22:00:00.186  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-06-12 22:00:00.186  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'MyApplication-1.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-06-12 22:00:00.186 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' completed its stop procedure
2020-06-12 22:00:00.186  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2020-06-12 22:00:00.187 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@72035809: 
2020-06-12 22:00:00.187 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.188 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'inetUtils': [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.188 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'inetUtils'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.188 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'taskScheduler'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.188  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.188 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#dd4aec3': [taskScheduler]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.188 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'mvcResourceUrlProvider': [requestMappingHandlerMapping]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.189 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'mvcValidator': [requestMappingHandlerAdapter]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.189 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter': [mvcUriComponentsContributor]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.189 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'mvcValidator'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.189 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'defaultValidator'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.189 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'exporter'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.189  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2020-06-12 22:00:00.189 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'jpaMappingContext': [repository2, repository2, fInputRepository, exceptionRepository, exclusionRepository, binRepository, repository1]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.190 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#39e69ea7': [repository2]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.190 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#6015a4a5': [(inner bean)#39e69ea7]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.190 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#5a8c93': [repository2]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.190 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#3bed3315': [(inner bean)#5a8c93]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.190 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#3ce443f9': [fInputRepository]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.190 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#57fbc06f': [(inner bean)#3ce443f9]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.191 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#64920dc2': [exceptionRepository]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.191 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#59a79443': [(inner bean)#64920dc2]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.191 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#167381c7': [exclusionRepository]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.191 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#608b1fd2': [(inner bean)#167381c7]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.191 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#47311277': [binRepository]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.191 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#7930ffa9': [(inner bean)#47311277]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#4833eff3': [repository1]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#4694f434': [(inner bean)#4833eff3]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'jpaMappingContext'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'springBatchSessionFactory': [springBatchSessionFactoryProvider, org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#3]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#3': [jpaContext]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'springBatchSessionFactory'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000031: Closing
2020-06-12 22:00:00.192 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles   : External cascade style registration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST] overrode base registration [STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.193 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl      : Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.193 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.b.r.i.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl   : Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.193 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'rSessionFactory': [rSessionFactoryProvider, org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'rSessionFactory'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000031: Closing
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles   : External cascade style registration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY] overrode base registration [STYLE_PERSIST]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl      : Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.b.r.i.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl   : Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'sessionFactory1': [sessionFactory1Provider, org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'sessionFactory1'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.194 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000031: Closing
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles   : External cascade style registration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY] overrode base registration [STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl      : Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.b.r.i.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl   : Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'fSessionFactory': [fSessionFactoryProvider, org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'fSessionFactory'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  : HHH000031: Closing
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadeStyles   : External cascade style registration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY] overrode base registration [STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.195 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl      : Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.h.b.r.i.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl   : Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'rEntityManagerFactory': [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#6, rTransactionManager]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'rEntityManagerFactory'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'firstDbEntityManagerFactory': [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#5, firstDbTransactionManager]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'firstDbEntityManagerFactory'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'fEntityManagerFactory': [fTransactionManager, org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#4]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'fEntityManagerFactory'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'characterEncodingFilter'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.196 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'requestContextFilter'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'tracing': [httpTracing, tracer, spanCustomizer, traceWebAspect, traceChannelInterceptor]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'httpTracing': [tracingFilter, tracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor, traceHttpClientBuilder]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'tracingFilter': [traceWebFilter]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'tracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor': [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfig$TraceInterceptorConfiguration]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'traceHttpClientBuilder': [apacheHttpClientFactory]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'tracer': [traceSchedulingAspect, traceAsyncAspect]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'traceChannelInterceptor': [tracingGlobalChannelInterceptorWrapper]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'tracing'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.c.c.s.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor : Unregistering job: job1
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.c.c.s.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor : Unregistering job: job2
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.c.c.s.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor : Unregistering job: job3
2020-06-12 22:00:00.197 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.c.c.s.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor : Unregistering job: job4
2020-06-12 22:00:00.198 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'batchEntityManagerFactory': [batchTransactionManager, org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#7]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.198 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'batchTransactionManager': [batchConfiguration]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.198 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'batchEntityManagerFactory'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.198  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.198 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'rDataSource': [rLiquibase]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.198 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'rDataSource'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.198  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-06-12 22:00:00.205  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Shutdown completed.
2020-06-12 22:00:00.205 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'fDataSource': [fLiquibase]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.205 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'fDataSource'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.206  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-06-12 22:00:00.209  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.
2020-06-12 22:00:00.209 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'batchDataSource': [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration, batchDataSourceInitializer, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.209 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'batchDataSource'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.209  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-06-12 22:00:00.211  INFO [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-06-12 22:00:00.211 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'refreshScope': [contextRefresher]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.211 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'contextRefresher': [refreshEventListener]
2020-06-12 22:00:00.211 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'refreshScope'
2020-06-12 22:00:00.211 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory': [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor]
```

I am not able to find the real reason behind the failure of this job.
The log level are in DEBUG mode but still no conclusive error is reported.

Upto the below line, the logs were showing as expected but after the below line, we can observe that the main thread is gone and Thread-9 comes in. Why the main thread is closed. Do Spring Batch have a default timelimit for thread?

```
select NuoDB_TABLE.* from TABLE2 NuoDB_TABLE where NuoDB_TABLE.COLUMN1=?
```

Also another observation:
The application is designed like:

- There is 1 JAR file (The application jar file), namely MyApplication_1.0.jar.
- Please consider 2 jobs designed inside that MyApplication1.0.jar.
- The scheduler will call the same MyApplication1.0.jar file for the 2 jobs with different parameters, like `java -jar MyApplication1.0.jar --job=job1` and `java -jar MyApplication1.0.jar --job=job2`
- The 2 jobs are scheduled accordingly,
  `Job1 is scheduled at 21:00 hours` and `Job2 is scheduled at 22:00 hours`.
- Please consider that Job1 deals with big file and it takes more than 1 hour to complete the job.
- So can there be a scenario that, Job1 was still running from 21:00 hours and at 22:00 hours, when the scheduler triggered Job2 at 22:00 hours, the Job1 thread failed instantly.

Comment: It looks like one of the jobs is closing the application context while the other job is still running. Package each job in its own jar and your issue will be solved by design.

Answer (score 0):

```
2020-06-12 22:00:00.086 DEBUG [MyApplication,,,] 16631 --- [           main] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
```

This line looks suspicious - is it possible that your batch just doesn't find anything to do and does a clean exit because of that?

Comment: No. It has code to handle if the result is zero. Its normal scenario